# Como "validar" o input

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estou procurando um método para verificar se os input's com required da página estão válidos toda vez que eu clico no botão salvar, mas estou tentando fazer isso sem ter que verificar um por um, segue abaixo o que eu já fiz.

obs: tive que deixar o button como "type='button'" por causa de algumas funções que terei que adicionar futuramente.

HTML:

```
<body>
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="last_name">Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date" required onfocus="(this.type='date')" placeholder="dd / mm / aaaa" onblur="(this.type='text')">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" placeholder=" ">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>CEP</label>
        <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" required placeholder=" " pattern="\d{2}\.\d{3}-?\d{3}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>CPF</label>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" required placeholder=" " pattern="\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}" maxlength="14">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>RG</label>
        <input type="text" name="rg" id="rg" required placeholder=" " pattern="\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{1}" maxlength="12">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>CNPJ</label>
        <input type="text" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" required placeholder=" " pattern="[0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Telefone Residencial</label>
        <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" required placeholder=" " pattern="[\(]\d{2}[\)][\s]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Telefone Celular</label>
        <input type="text" name="cel" id="cel" required placeholder=" " pattern="[\(]\d{2}[\)][\s]\d{1}[\s]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="salve">salvar</button>
</form>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/mascara.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"]:invalid:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown),
input[type="date"]:invalid:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown),
input[type="email"]:invalid:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown){
    border-color:red;
    border-width: 3px;
}
input:valid {
    border-color:green;
    border-width: 3px;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#value").mask("#.##0,00", { reverse: true });
$("#telefone").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
$("#cel").mask("(00) 0 0000-0000");
$("#cpf").mask("#00.000.000-00", { reverse: true });
$("#rg").mask("#0.000.000-0", { reverse: true });
$("#cep").mask("00.000-000");
$("#cnpj").mask("00.000.000/0000-00");

var salve = $("#salve");
salve.on("click", function() {

//verificar se os inputs estão vazios
var vazios = $("input").filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
}).get();

console.log(vazios);

if (vazios.length) {
    $(vazios).addClass('vazio');
    console.log("Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos.");
    return false;
}else {
    console.log("Eureka");
}

// tentativa de verificar se os inputs estão validos
var validos = $("input").filter(function() {
    return this.valid;
}).get();
console.log(validos);
});
```

no caso eu coloquei uma validação visual nos inputs e consegui verificar se os inputs estão vazios, só não estou conseguindo validar se eles estão preenchidos corretamente

Comment: Não teria como usar o JS pra identificar se os inputs receberam o css" input:valid" e fazer a verificação a partir dele? é mais ou menos isso que eu estava tentando fazer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no retorno do `filter`. Você deve verificar o elemento com a *pseudo-classe* `:valid` desta forma, usando o método `.is`:

```
var validos = $("input").filter(function() {
       return $(this).is(":valid"); // valida o campo. Retorna true ou false
   }).get();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 1):

Podes criar uma função que chama no subumit assim você pode retornar mensagem, mudar a cor da borda do css ou outra coisa que queira:

```
    function validaDados() {
            var mensagem = "";
            //Guia Geral
            if ($("#input1").val() == null || $("#representante").val() == "") {
                $("#input1").css({ "border-color": "#F00", "padding": "1px" });
                $("#errorinput1").html("é obrigatório");
                mensagem = "1";
            } else {
                $("#input1").css({ "border-color": "blue", "padding": "1px" });
                $("#errorinput1").html("");
            }

            if (mensagem != "")//se a variavel mensagem tiver  conteudo,ou seja ,se tiver ocorrido ,algum erro no preenchimento
            {
                $("#resposta").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                $('#resposta').html('Verifique o formulário, existem campos obrigatórios não preenchidos');
                $('#resposta').show(); //MOSTRA A DIV DE RESPOSTA
                return false;
            } else { // se não
                $('#resposta').html('');
                $('#resposta').hide();

                return true;
            }
        }
```